# Hide / remove space taken by div from html with css only after animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to "physically" remove, or have the div (for example) not take up space on the screen after hidden.

I added another div below the #test div to show that after #test is hidden, it still takes up space on the screen. Is there a way to have that space be gone, with css only?

```css
#test {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeinout 3s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadeinout 3s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadeinout 3s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadeinout 3s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadeinout 3s;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeinout {
  /* Firefox */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeinout {
  /* Opera */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">hide me after 3 seconds</div>
<div>After 3 seconds I don't move up.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also animate the max-height - just make sure that the middle max-height is taller than your tallest fading div

```css
#test {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeinout 3s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadeinout 3s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadeinout 3s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadeinout 3s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadeinout 3s;
    max-height: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  from {
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 5em;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">hide me after 3 seconds</div>
<div>After 3 seconds I don't move up.</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.